# Is the flash storage firmware update 1.0 for my MBA installed? How can I verify it?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, firmware

On  May 16th 2013 Apple released the **[MacBook Air Flash Storage Firmware Update 1.0](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1655)**. Since I have experienced the described symptoms I really want this update.

However, the Mac App Store will show that **I can still update the Firmware (again) after a restart**. Since I waited for one minute, as required in the update description, I do not know what's going on.

After three attempts to install the update the Mac App Store still offers to install it once again...

The update description also mentions:

> Boot ROM or SMC Version Information: After the update, you will have Revision TPVABBF0.

How can I check latter version information, in case this is a bug in the Mac App Store app only and the firmware update has been installed successfully?

Comment: Same issue here. AFter the update I dont see "Revision TPVABBF0" Boot ROM Version: MBA51.00EF.B02
SMC Version (system): 2.4f17

Comment: @dds And how did you out the boot rom version?

Comment: I cannot get it to install either. I'm suspecting it has something to do with **FileVault 2** which I am using on this MBAir… @gentmatt- you can get the Boot ROM by >About This Mac… More Info… System Report…

Comment: @Meltemi Thanks! I see only `Boot ROM Version: MBA51.00EF.B02`and `SMC Version (system): 2.5f7` (yes, it's `2.5f7` not `2.4f17`. No mention of `TPVABBF0`. I also have Filevault 2 enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system_profiler SPSerialATADataType | awk '/Revision/ { print $2 }'
```

That should get you the current firmware version of your SSD.

TPVABBF0 = has update

TPSABBF0 = does not have update

Comment: Thanks! Of course this is the proper way to do it. I was too blind to check the system profiler...

Answer (score 2):

#### Firmware update and FileVault

A [forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13806179&postcount=4) suggests that Firmware updates require access to `/System/...` in addition to the EFI partition (`disk0s1`).

Since `/System/...` is located on the startup volume it is encrypted if you have **FileVault 2** enabled - due to Full Disk Encryption.

If you search further down in `/System/...` you will find the Revision number mentioned in the Apple [knowledge-base document](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1655) for this Firmware update`TPVABBF0`:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Firmware Updates/HardDriveUpdate3/HDFW/APPLE_SSD_TS128E TPVABBF0
```

However, this alone is **not** a guarantee that the Firmware update has been installed. Before I had successfully applied the update, the contents already looked like this:

[image]

### How to install...

Since there is no way around the encryption, I **disabled FileVault** - applied the update - and re-enabled FileVault.

You will notice that the update is installing if you see a grey bar during the boot process above which is a standard hard drive icon.

After the update, all the folders in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Firmware Updates/...` as you can see in the picture are still present and the `Boot ROM Version: MBA51.00EF.B02` and `SMC Version (system): 2.5f7` have not changed either.

While the Mac App Store still has the red badge for "new updates" it does not offer anymore to install the firmware update. So, I *guess* the firmware update has been installed successfully...

Answer (score 1):

After disabling FileVault 2 you might have to do a SMC reset to have a successful update ( and new revision ). See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964 to see how. If you've been successful can be seen in your systeminformation panel under Hardware -> Serial-ATA -> Version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this is how I finally got the update to install.

1. disable firmware password
2. disable filevault
3. reboot and shutdown
4. [reset PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379)
5. reboot
6. install the [update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1655) (when the update was done, my mba was shut down, so I had to power it on again myself)
7. (enable filevault and firmware password again)

You can check if the update was successfully installed from the system info app, on the serial ATA tab. There the harddisk is listed with its revision number which should now be TPVABBF0.